# Can not save Tensorflow model when it contains batchnormalization layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to save a custom Tensorflow model after 1 epoch training. When the model contains BatchNormalization layer it can not be saved. I can see that "fused_batch_norm" is can not be serialized. How can I call another BatchNormalization layer which can be serialized and saved with both ".h5" and ".pb" format. I am using Tensorflow 2.8 with Tensorflow-metal on MacOS.

```
def conv_batchnorm_relu(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=1):
    # s
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding = 'same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
    return x
```

> TypeError: Layer tf.compat.v1.nn.fused_batch_norm was passed non-JSON-serializable arguments. Arguments had types: {'scale': <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>, 'offset': <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>, 'mean': <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>, 'variance': <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>, 'epsilon': <class 'float'>, 'is_training': <class 'bool'>, 'data_format': <class 'str'>}. They cannot be serialized out when saving the model.

Edit: I used `tf.keras.layers.experimental.SyncBatchNormalization()`function instead of `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()` and problem solved for now.

Comment: please include a full example that we can run, specially the imports.

Comment: You really need to include more code, you have people guessing the problem in the answers section.

Comment: There are 200 layers like above but BatchNormalization function used just above function. Btw, I solved the problem with SyncBatchNormalization layer. Maybe this problem occurs on Tensorflow Metal.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply matrix properties or you can create a model with a support function.

**Sample:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import h5py

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
filters = 32
kernel_size = (3, 3)
strides = 1

database_buffer = "F:\\models\\buffer\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
database_buffer_dir = os.path.dirname(database_buffer)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
if not exists(database_buffer_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(database_buffer_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + database_buffer_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""   
def conv_batchnorm_relu(filters, kernel_size, strides=1):
    
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 3 )),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding = 'same'),
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    ])
        
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10))
    model.summary()
    
    return model

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
# Create hdf5 file
hdf5_file = h5py.File(database_buffer, mode='w')

# Train images
hdf5_file['x_train'] = train_images
hdf5_file['y_train'] = train_labels

# Test images
hdf5_file['x_test'] = test_images
hdf5_file['y_test'] = test_labels

hdf5_file.close()

# Visualize dataset train sample
hdf5_file = h5py.File(database_buffer,  mode='r')

x_train = hdf5_file['x_train'][0: 10000]
x_test = hdf5_file['x_test'][0: 100]
y_train = hdf5_file['y_train'][0: 10000]
y_test = hdf5_file['y_test'][0: 100]

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = conv_batchnorm_relu(filters, kernel_size, strides=1)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1 ,validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

input('...')
```

Comment: I do not get the difference between my code and yours. Is the problem 'cause of Functional API? Do I need to use Sequential API?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your given template is, you can not use support function this way for adding custom layers in your model. Typically you inherit from **keras.Model** when you need the model methods like: **Model.fit** ,**Model.evaluate**, and **Model.save**

Here is a example code for better understanding

```
class ExampleBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filter1,filter2):
    super(ExampleBlock, self).__init__(name='')
    
    self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))
    self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
    self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    
   # You can as many layer you like

  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
    x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2b(x)
    x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```

After defining your model you can create checkpoint after each epoch by defining the call back function.

```
import keras
model_save_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Project/" #path for saving checkpoint
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_save_path+'checkpoint_{epoch:02d}', save_freq='epoch')
```

You can use this checkpoint in the callback funtion

```
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS), validation_data=(validX, validY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS, epochs=EPOCHS,
    class_weight=classWeight,
    verbose=1,callbacks=[checkpoint])
```